# Why isn't jumping against a wall an elastic collision?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

According to this calculator http://www.abecedarical.com/javascript/script_collision1d.html when low mass object hits high mass object it is reflected gaining opposite velocity almost the same as initial velocity.

If I jump onto the wall why my body is not reflected? I know that collision is not fully elastic but it should be at least similar.

Comment: Not fully elastic is an understatement. That collision is very inelastic. All the squishiness of the human body and its ability to spread out and change shape. Not very elastic indeed.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the wall. yhgdfg should be more specific about the setup of the experiment. How often did he jump against the wall? Which body parts hit it first? I only want to avoid closing of the question due to insufficient effort.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_cat_bounce

Comment: ""If I jump onto the wall why my body is not reflected?"" Maybe it is reflected! Try! Physics is an experimantal sciene.

Comment: @Georg Does 1800 PLASTERER get you a good repair job afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

An elastic collision is defined as one which conserves energy. When you jump against a wall, most of your kinetic energy is dissipated as heat into your tissue as your legs and muscles absorb the impact. Therefore, energy is not conserved so by definition this is an inelastic collision.

Answer (score 0):

Changing shape could still be an elastic deformation (of a rigid body). So obviously there are also plastic deformations involved, when jumping against a wall.